# How to parse EXIF Date Time data

Tags: c#, datetime, exif

I am writing a C# program that extracts the EXIF `DateTimeOriginal` field from a JPEG file, if that property is in the data, and I need to parse it into a `DateTime` value.

The code I have is:

```
BitmapFrame src = decoder.Frames[ 0 ];

if ( src.Metadata != null ) {
    BitmapMetadata metaData = (BitmapMetadata) src.Metadata;

    if ( metaData.ContainsQuery( "/app1/{ushort=0}/{ushort=34665}/{ushort=36867}" ) ) {
        object o = metaData.GetQuery( "/app1/{ushort=0}/{ushort=34665}/{ushort=36867}" );

        if ( o != null && o is string ) {
            string originalDate = Convert.ToString( o );

            if ( originalDate != null ) {
                if ( !DateTime.TryParseExact( originalDate.Trim(), "yyyy:MM:dd hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out createDate ) ) {
                    // Sets createDate to a default value if the date doesn't parse.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, the format string in the call to `TryParseExact` doesn't work, as the code executes the code that is replaced with the comment.

What's the right way to write the format string?  The value in the `DateTimeOriginal` property is formatted as YYYY:MM:DD HH:MM:SS.  It's the colons in between the YYYY, MM, and DD specifiers that are killing me.  Why'd they use colons??

**EDIT**

I tried changing the format specifier string to "yyyy\:MM\dd hh\:mm:\ss" but that didn't work, either.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a code snippet from an *old* program I have lying around that does something very similar to this:

```
string dateTakenText;
using (Image photo = Image.FromFile(file.Name))
{
    PropertyItem pi = photo.GetPropertyItem(Program.propertyTagExifDTOrig_);
    ASCIIEncoding enc = new ASCIIEncoding();
    dateTakenText = enc.GetString(pi.Value, 0, pi.Len - 1);
}
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateTakenText))
{
    continue;
}
DateTime dateTaken;
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTakenText, "yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss",
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTaken))
{
    continue;
}
```

This code snippet sits inside a `foreach` loop, which explains the use of the `continue` keyword.

This is code from a program I wrote sometime back in 2002 or 2003, and I've been using it regularly since then; it works pretty reliably.

Comment: But hey, `var`s man, my eyes (and an `Encoding.ASCII`) :D Computer History Museum stuff :)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Mark Seemann & Markus, I got this figured out finally.  The time in the EXIF data is in 24 hour / military time.  The "hh" format specifier in the string is for 12 hour time with an AM/PM.   The time I was passing was at 14:14, or 2:14 PM.  In 12 hour time, "14" is an invalid time.

So the correct format specifier is "yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss".

Answer (score 2):

This [link](http://snipplr.com/view/25074/date-taken-exif-data-for-a-picture/) describes a way that parses the individual parts of the string instead of parsing it using DateTime.Parse:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the EXIF Image Data of the Date Taken.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="getImage">Image (If based on a file use Image.FromFile(f);)</param>
/// <returns>Date Taken or Null if Unavailable</returns>
public static DateTime? DateTaken(Image getImage)
{
    int DateTakenValue = 0x9003; //36867;

    if (!getImage.PropertyIdList.Contains(DateTakenValue))
        return null;

    string dateTakenTag = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(getImage.GetPropertyItem(DateTakenValue).Value);
    string[] parts = dateTakenTag.Split(':', ' ');
    int year = int.Parse(parts[0]);
    int month = int.Parse(parts[1]);
    int day = int.Parse(parts[2]);
    int hour = int.Parse(parts[3]);
    int minute = int.Parse(parts[4]);
    int second = int.Parse(parts[5]);

    return new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
}
```

Comment: FYI, to use `PropertyIdList.Contains()` you must include `using System.Linq`.

Answer (score 2):

I recently rewrote the application that I mention in my other answer. This time, I wrote it in F#. The relevant part doing the work is this:

```
[<Literal>]
let private exifDateTaken = 0x0132

[<Literal>]
let private exifDateTimeOriginal = 0x9003

let private tryParseDate s =
    let res =
        DateTime.TryParseExact(
            s,
            "yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss",
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            DateTimeStyles.None)
    match res with
    | true, dt -> Some dt
    | _ -> None

let extractDateTaken (fi : FileInfo) =
    let extractExif (img : Image) exif =
        if img.PropertyIdList |> Array.contains exif
        then
            let pi = img.GetPropertyItem exif
            Some (Encoding.ASCII.GetString(pi.Value, 0, pi.Len - 1))
        else None

    use photo = Image.FromFile fi.FullName

    [ exifDateTimeOriginal; exifDateTaken ]
    |> Seq.choose (extractExif photo)
    |> Seq.tryHead
    |> Option.bind tryParseDate
```